# Would it be accurate to say that JAXB is to XML as Hibernate is to a database schema?

Tags: java, hibernate, jaxb

If I want an ORM that helps me to develop a "database agnostic" application, then Hibernate would be a good fit, but if I need to map entities or objects to nodes in an XML file, then JAXB would be the right type of technology... would that be a correct assessment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, JAXB is intended for binding Java objects to XML and vice-versa.  It is not an exact analogy, imo, but I think I see what you are getting at.  :)

Answer (score 1):

More accurately, JAXB is to XML as JPA is to a database schema.

JAXB and JPA are specifications with multiple implementations.  Where JPA has TopLink/EclipseLink, Hibernate, ...  JAXB has TopLink/EclipseLink, Metro, ...